# Increasing div's width

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my divs. I created 3 divs with same classes. I want to create 3 cards with avatar and personal info on them, but these divs are "sticked". I want to make a gap between them (from right side), but when I make padding-right, there's no gap, but more background color. How can I separate these three divs without changing width?

Here's my code:

```
<div id="team">
    <div class="id">
        <div class="idContent">
      <!--Here is content in a frame!-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="id">
        <div class="idContent">
      <!--Here is content in a frame!-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="id">
        <div class="idContent">
      <!--Here is content in a frame!-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PbMBPy

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `margin-right: 25px;` instead of `padding-right: 25px;`

Comment: No problem, powodzenia ;)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

use margin-right instead of padding-right